# jdbi-jpa with jakarta.persistence

Tags: jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi-jpa

I'm using JDBI in testing, and where it is often practical to directly peek in the database. To reduce mapping issues jdbi-jpa prevent naming columns twice, so it could be quite handy... If it would be using the Jakarta annotations instead of javax.

https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/945755b6e6b02795cca7b161c683c344974f8640/jpa/src/main/java/org/jdbi/v3/jpa/JpaMapperFactory.java#L19

Any plans on providing a Jakarta compatible version?